# Rails: best practice to load a helper in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I was hired some days ago to update a Rails 4 app. In general the rspecs and the code look good however in the top of some controller a found this line:

```
 delegate :edit_app_path, :new_app_payment_path, to: :view_context
```

Searching in the net, I found that the line is a way to load methods from the helpers inside a controller through a new instance of ActionView::Base class. I mean, is a way to do it instead of the classic:

```
include MyHelper
```

in the controller. My question is: is this really a good practice? is faster? AFAIK, **view_context** will load a new class with **all** the helpers and all the context of the view instead of one helper if I use the classic "include MyHelper". By the way *:edit_app_path* and *:new_app_payment_path* methods are in the same helper.

Should I remove the line?

Comment: it seems that your guess is off. Is `edit_app_path` really in a helper? It looks like routing method, which _should_ be available in controllers without doing anything.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev,  yeah is a dynamic route, because some routes are created reading the rows of a table. The helper do something like:

      **send("new_#{@agency.slug}_app_payment_path", application)**

but that is another question ;-)

Comment: Does it work if you `include MyHelper`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `view_context` allows the controller to be blissfully ignorant of where the path is defined. If the helper file structure is refactored in future, the controller will continue humming along without requiring change.

Performance wise, I doubt the impact will be significant since all the code will have been loaded. Rails (and the Ruby standard library) creates new objects all the time.